# What virtuemart file to edit when saving order details after purchasing product?

Tags: joomla2.5, cart, virtuemart

Do you know what file to edit when you want to save order details in database after purchasing product in virtuemart 2?

I want to save some order details into another table after purchasing. But I don't know what file to modify, I found the controller as well as view files for the cart but can't find the model where the data are inserted to database. We are currently using Joomla 2.5.17 and Virtuemart 2.0.26,

Answer (score 1):

In VM 2.x you can find the related controller as `cart.php` have a function `confirm()`.
It calls a function from cart helper file. `confirmDone()` you can add your custom function inside any of these function or directly in `order.php` model file on admin side.

These function accessing time you will get cart session so all the cart items data will be available inside these functions.

Hope its helps..

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sir. I've already managed to add details in the table that I manually created in joomla based on the orders created.

Comment: These are the files and functions related to order functionality.